# jQuery highlighting special characters in text

Tags: jquery, highlight

I am using

**JavaScript text higlighting jQuery plugin**
http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

It works well for me all the time, except for some symbols:

```
$("#preview").highlight($(this).val(), { wordsOnly: true, className: 'blacklist'});
```

if "$(this).val()" equals to either €, $ or £ - highlight plugin doesn't work. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Could you post an example on http://jsbin.com/ so that others could try to debug it for you?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know exacly why it doesn't work, but the plugin is intended to highlight words/chars, not really special chars. It may have to do with that fact, being special chars. Check if the code you're trying to highlight isn't encoding those special chars to something like `&euro;`